# Entity Framework HasForeignKey not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I run into a strange behavior of HasForeignKey in EF 6.2.

Class Consignment has two properties Customer and Sender:

```
public class Consignment
{
    public Consignment()
    {
        Sender = new Sender();
        Customer = new Customer();
    }

    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Sender Sender { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

CustomerId is foreign key for Customer. Entities configured as follows:

```
    public class ConsignmentEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Consignment>
{
    public ConsignmentEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(s => s.OrderNo);

        HasRequired(x => x.Customer)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CustomerId);

        HasRequired(x => x.Sender)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("SenderId"));
    }
}

public class SenderEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Sender>
{
    public SenderEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Number);
    }
}

public class CustomerEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

Customer ans Sender configured almost identically, except Customer configures with HasForeignKey property, and Sender configured with Map property.

So, when I getting Consignment from db, like in query

```
var consignment = context.Set<Consignment>().Include(x => x.Customer).Include(x => x.Sender).FirstOrDefault();
```

i recieve consignment with right Sender, but  with empty Customer (all properties is null or empty). Eager, lazy and explicitly loading produces the same results.

SQL Server gets and projects Customer normally, but EF returns empty Customer (like after new Customer())

So, when I remove CustomerId property from model, and configure Customer with .Map, all works perfectly.

```
         HasRequired(x => x.Customer)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("CustomerId"));
```

When I recreates the same model in new test project (with simple classes), HasForeignKey working as expected.

What am I missing in original project? Classes a pretty simple, and I triple checked all configurations, original project and test project looks the same, but working differently...

Slightly simplified classes:

```
public class Sender
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding in Customer

```
public virtual ICollection<Consignment> Consignments { get; set; }
```

and change to

```
HasRequired(x => x.Customer)
            .WithMany(x=>x.Consignments)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CustomerId);
```

Comment: Tried, didn't help. Also the question more about "what can affect a simple behavior of foreign key, in such a way", not how to fix it. It works perfectly fine in other projects with similar contexts.